# ld: framework not found AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I get linking error when trying to compile iOS project from terminal with Xcode 7.1.1:

> xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -target MyProject build

As result I receive next error:

> ld: framework not found AFNetworking
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target "MyProject" do
  pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'MONActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'NYXImagesKit'
  pod 'MagicalRecord'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'Countly'
end

xcodeproj 'MyProject'
```

I also tried adding link_with but get the same error. How to fix the problem above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build using the workspace generated by CocoaPods:
`xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyProject build`

If you build just the project, `xcodebuild` does not see the dependency on the Pods project.  Note that you have to use a scheme when building a workspace rather than a target.  This means if you are building on a build server you will need to mark your scheme as shared in the scheme editor.